# Couple issue with custom camera

Tags: swift, swift3, camera, avcapturesession, avcapturedevice

I currently have a custom camera implemented into my application. I am running into two small issues.

1) When I switch b/w the views of the camera (front & back) the audio input dies, and only records video.

2) My method for deciding which camera view (front & back) is which, is depreciated, & I don't know how to exactly go about resolving it. For this one, the code is as follows: The depreciated part is the devices is storing as its variables. xCode is telling me: "Use AVCaptureDeviceDiscoverySession instead."

```
  let devices = AVCaptureDevice.devices(withMediaType: AVMediaTypeVideo) as! [AVCaptureDevice]

    // Get the front and back-facing camera for taking photos
    for device in devices {
        if device.position == AVCaptureDevicePosition.back {
            backFacingCamera = device

        } else if device.position == AVCaptureDevicePosition.front {
            frontFacingCamera = device
        }
    }
    currentDevice = backFacingCamera
    guard let captureDeviceInput = try? AVCaptureDeviceInput(device: currentDevice) else {
        return
    }
```

As for the general camera recording here are the codes:

My Variables:

```
 let captureSession = AVCaptureSession()
        var currentDevice:AVCaptureDevice?
        var backFacingCamera: AVCaptureDevice?
        var frontFacingCamera: AVCaptureDevice?
        var videoFileOutput : AVCaptureMovieFileOutput?
        var cameraPreviewLayer : AVCaptureVideoPreviewLayer?
        @IBOutlet weak var recordingView: UIView!
```

switching cameras:

```
 var device = AVCaptureDevice.defaultDevice(withDeviceType: .builtInWideAngleCamera, mediaType: AVMediaTypeVideo, position: .back)
         func switchCameras() {
                captureSession.beginConfiguration()

                // Change the device based on the current camera
                let newDevice = (currentDevice?.position == AVCaptureDevicePosition.back) ? frontFacingCamera : backFacingCamera

                // Remove all inputs from the session
                for input in captureSession.inputs {
                    captureSession.removeInput(input as! AVCaptureDeviceInput)
                }

                // Change to the new input
                let cameraInput:AVCaptureDeviceInput
                do {
                    cameraInput = try AVCaptureDeviceInput(device: newDevice)
                } catch {
                    print(error)
                    return
                }

                if captureSession.canAddInput(cameraInput) {
                    captureSession.addInput(cameraInput)
                }

                currentDevice = newDevice
                captureSession.commitConfiguration()

                if currentDevice?.position == .front {
                    flashButton.isHidden = true
                    flashButton.isEnabled = false
                } else if currentDevice?.position == .back {
                    flashButton.isHidden = false
                    flashButton.isEnabled = true
                }

            }
```

& In my view will appear:

```
mediaViewCapture.frame = CGRect(x: self.view.frame.size.width * 0, y: self.view.frame.size.height * 0, width:self.view.frame.size.width, height: self.view.frame.size.height)
        self.view.addSubview(mediaViewCapture)

        captureSession.sessionPreset = AVCaptureSessionPresetHigh

        let devices = AVCaptureDevice.devices(withMediaType: AVMediaTypeVideo) as! [AVCaptureDevice]

        // Get the front and back-facing camera for taking photos
        for device in devices {
            if device.position == AVCaptureDevicePosition.back {
                backFacingCamera = device

            } else if device.position == AVCaptureDevicePosition.front {
                frontFacingCamera = device
            }
        }
        currentDevice = backFacingCamera
        guard let captureDeviceInput = try? AVCaptureDeviceInput(device: currentDevice) else {
            return
        }

        let audioInputDevice = AVCaptureDevice.defaultDevice(withMediaType: AVMediaTypeAudio)

        do
        {
            let audioInput = try AVCaptureDeviceInput(device: audioInputDevice)

            // Add Audio Input
            if captureSession.canAddInput(audioInput)
            {
                captureSession.addInput(audioInput)
            }
            else
            {
                NSLog("Can't Add Audio Input")
            }
        }
        catch let error
        {
            NSLog("Error Getting Input Device: \(error)")
        }

        videoFileOutput = AVCaptureMovieFileOutput()
        captureSession.addInput(captureDeviceInput)
        captureSession.addOutput(videoFileOutput)
        cameraPreviewLayer = AVCaptureVideoPreviewLayer(session: captureSession)
        view.layer.addSublayer(cameraPreviewLayer!)
        cameraPreviewLayer?.videoGravity = AVLayerVideoGravityResizeAspectFill
        cameraPreviewLayer?.frame = mediaViewCapture.layer.frame
        captureSession.startRunning()
```

& Finally my capture:

```
func capture(_ captureOutput: AVCaptureFileOutput!, didFinishRecordingToOutputFileAt outputFileURL: URL!, fromConnections connections: [Any]!, error: Error!) {
    if error == nil {
        turnFlashOff()
        let videoVC = VideoPreviewVC()
        videoVC.url = outputFileURL
        self.navigationController?.pushViewController(videoVC, animated: false)
    } else {
        print("Error saving the video \(error)")
    }
    }
```

Comment: You usually add the audio device too, in your change device function you remove all devices and only add a video device and not an audio device

Answer (score 1):

You can look use AVCaptureDeviceDiscoverySession instead of AVCaptureDevice as it is deprecated following is the code for it:

```
let deviceDiscovery = AVCaptureDeviceDiscoverySession(deviceTypes: [AVCaptureDeviceType.builtInWideAngleCamera], mediaType: AVMediaTypeVideo, position: .back)
        let devices = deviceDiscovery?.devices
        for device in devices! {
            if device.hasMediaType(AVMediaTypeVideo) {
                captureDevice = device
            }
        }
```

AVCaptureDeviceType has following types: builtInMicrophone, builtInWideAngleCamera, builtInTelephotoCamera, builtInDualCamera and builtInDuoCamera.

Need to check the audioInput issue when camera is switched.